# Как обрезать длинную строку в IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, css

как обрезать длинную строку в IE8. Перепробовал несколько вариантов ничего не вышло. Сейчас у меня выглядит это так:

```
.serversName {
vertical-align: top;
padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
max-width: 183px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden; }
```

В Chrome обрезает. Тестирую так:
У меня стоит минимальная ширина сайта 920px. Я зажимаю клавишу CTRL и увеличиваю сайт. Когда он доходит до нужной ширины строка начинает обрезаться и добавляются 3 точки. А в IE8 все правила в стилях игнорируется, рушиться сетка сайта.

Кто то сталкивался с такой задачей и как мудрее поступить в ней?
Вот сайт на котором я это делаю: [Перейти на сайт](http://youarena.ru/)

Comment: какой тег у `.serversName`?

Comment: <td class="serversName">☞ ZERO ZONE 1 ☞ x3-x6/RUST-RPG/Kit/TP/Clan/Barren/Wipe02.11 сервер Rust</td>

Comment: скорее всего в этом проблема. IE сейчас воспользоваться и проверить не могу. Попробуйте текст в ячейке отдельно обернуть в div и указать ему `max-width: 100%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden`

Comment: Не работает. Если просто поставить width: 200px; то он обрезает. Но тогда текст всегда обрезанный даже если места для строки полно.

Comment: поддерживать ie8 в 2018м году? вы серьезно? доля использования - сотые доли процента.

Comment: Думаете и правда не стоит? Я просто думал так, если в IE8 всё пучком работает значит и в других работает :)

Comment: особенно когда речь идет об игровых сайтах, где аудитория априори - молодые и активные пользователи, использующие далеко не старое железо, и ПО. У вас в статистике доступа этот браузер хоть встречается, хотя бы раз?

Comment: Вы умете убеждать :)

Comment: Проверил на другом своем игровом сайта, 1 раз) ну это наверное я :)

Comment: Скажите будет ли правильно сделать так: Через php определить какой браузер использует и запретить те браузеры на которых сайт отображается не корректно и выводил содержимое что вы используете устаревший браузер пожалуйста обновите.